# How to install a package from the universe repository?

Tags: apt, ppa

**System Specs:** I am running Ubuntu 17.10.

**Goal:** I am trying to install [libweston-3-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libweston-3-0), which I think is from the universe repository.

Running

```
$ apt-cache search weston
libweston-1-0 - reference implementation of a wayland compositor (shared libs)
libweston-1-dev - reference implementation of a wayland compositor (shared libs)
weston - reference implementation of a wayland compositor
```

Doesn't show the package. How am I able to get this package installed on my system?

Comment: The package you want is in Bionic - 18.04 to be released in April 2018. 17.10 only has version libweston-1-0.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Is there any way to consume this package without waiting until April 2018?

Answer (score 1):

The package [libweston-3-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libweston-3-0) is from bionic (ubuntu 18.04) repository, and you're running artful (17.10), that is why you cant find it with apt.

Possible solutions:

1. Download package manually from bionic repo and try to install it (you may experience dependencies problems).
2. Download sources for libweston-3-0 and rebuild it for artful (long way).
3. Upgrate ubuntu to bionic.
4. Try to find ppa with libweston-3-0 for artful, note that it can have different name (you can use web search or search at https://launchpad.net/ ).